# C# Sorting a priority queue based on a linked list

Tags: c#, data-structures, priority-queue

I'm developing an implementation of a priority queue using a linked list (nodes) as the underlying data structure. Up to this point, I'm able to enqueue my data from a file of mock data, however my sort method is not working correctly. I suspect the problem is with my references to the head and tail. Note : there are 1000 rows in the CSV I'm reading from.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@file_Path))
{
    //creates head of linked list
    Node newNode = new Node(reader.ReadLine().Split(','), rand.Next(1000));
    current = head = newNode;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        //creates next node after head until end of file
        current._right = new Node(reader.ReadLine().Split(','), rand.Next(1000));

        //if the tail exists, the oldest node is the new tail
        if (tail != null) current._left = tail;

        tail = current;
        //sets the current node to the next node in the list so while loop continues.
        current = current._right;
        //Sort();
    }
}

public static void Dequeue()
{
    Sort();
    if (tail != null)
    {
        current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LastName: " + current.Data.last_name + "\t\t\tFirstName: " + current.Data.first_name + " \t\tRandomNumber: " + current.Data.randomValue.value);
            current = current._right;
        }
    }
}

public static void Sort()
{
    int length = 0;
    comparable = tail;
    current = head;


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < length; b++)
        {
            while (current != null && comparable != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.randomValue.value > comparable.Data.randomValue.value)
                {
                    Swap(current, comparable);
                }
                if (current.Data.randomValue.value < comparable.Data.randomValue.value)
                {
                    Swap(comparable, current);
                }

                current = comparable._left;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you reading all the nodes and then you want to sort them into Priority Queue order, or are you trying to build a priority queue from the the file input? If the later, you're not building a priority queue, it's just a linked list. Normally when you're building the PQ, you insert each element into the correct position from the beginning and then the head element is the highest priority item, and you maintain priority sorting each time to insert or remove an item.

Comment: Yeah I realized this when I came back to look at my notes when trying to solve this, thank you.